# Xanatos is getting bored... but when and where?

Tags: episode-identification, gargoyles-1994

There is the following conversation in the "Gargoyles - The Goliath Chronicles":

> David Xanatos: Sorry to cut short your reunion, but frankly, I'm getting bored!
>
> [Helicopters appear and they capture the Gargoyles]
>
> Goliath: Are you *insane*?
>
> David Xanatos: Funny question coming from a file clerk who thinks he's a gargoyle!
>
> Goliath: The Xanatos I knew had given up such cruelty
>
> David Xanatos: Foolish man.

What episode is this from? Is there a clip of this somewhere in the internet?

Comment: Where did you find the quote?  Are there clues in the source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0585863/quotes) the quote comes from Episode 10 "[For It May Come True](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0585863/)."

This appears to be the relevant timestamp: